# Z-index doesn't work on pseudo element ::after

Tags: html, css

I want the white circle above the inner circle. I can't see why the z-index doesn't work when the wrapper has a position relative and no z-index. I did something similar in a previous challenge on site css battle and it worked.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<style>
  body{
    display:grid;
    place-content:center;
    background-color:#191919;
  }
  .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #E08027;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #824B20;
    
    
      
  }
  
 
  .wrapper::before {
    content:'';
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20;
    left:-20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 110px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
    border: 20px solid #FFF58F;
    border-top:0px;
    z-index:5;
   
}
   
  
  
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<div class="wrapper">
</div>
<style>
  body{
    display:grid;
    place-content:center;
    background-color:#191919;
  }
  .wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background: #E08027;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px #824B20;
    
    
      
  }
  
 
  .wrapper::before {
    content:'';
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20;
    left:-20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 110px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 110px;
    border: 20px solid #FFF58F;
    border-top:0px;
    z-index:5;
   
}
   
  
  
</style>
```

I'm not sure if I understood your request but tell me if that helps when you remove the `overflow: hidden;` (try running the snippet above)